# How to insatll NVIDIA 440 compulsorily on Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, cuda

When I tried to install pytorch on the Ubuntu 20.04 based on the instruction from the pytorch website, it requires cuda 10.2 or 11.3 which corresponding to NVIDIA driver 440 or 465. Each time when I tried to install 440 or 465 using the code

```
sudo apt install nvidia-utils-440
```

or

```
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-440
```

it will finnally install NVIDIA driver 470.
[additional packages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z4FSN.png) [new packages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BdhTP.png)
After reboot and chekc with the code

```
nvidia-smi
```

the result is [nvidia-smi](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WAjnl.png)

Then I tried to install it manually. So I downloaded the run file from NVIDIA, but still cannot succeed.
Can anyone help me how to deal with that? Is it because the available driver only has 515 510 470? [additional driver](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SW186.png)

Comment: Yes, it's because what you want to install are now transitional packages. And where exactly are those instructions asking specifically for CUDA 10.2 or 11.3? Here https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/ it says *Often, the latest CUDA version is better*.

Comment: A RTX A5000 should be running with 515 (or newer when available) and the corresponding  CUDA version and BOTH, driver and CUDA, should be installed from the Ubuntu repositories, not with the Nvidia's binaries.